# Some values skipped when iterating through a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, image-processing, iterator, python-imaging-library

I'm writing a Python program using PIL that needs, for each pixel, to find the values of all pixels within 5 pixels of that pixel. To find where all these pixels are, I wrote the following code:

```
#w and h are dimensions of the image
for y in range(h):
    for x in range(w):
        #find neighboring pixels
        neighbors = [(x+x2,x+y2) for x2 in range(-5,5) for y2 in range(-5, 5)]
        for i, (x2, y2) in enumerate(neighbors):
            if x2 < 0 or y2 < 0:
                neighbors.pop(i)
            if x2 > w or y2 > h:
                neighbors.pop(i)
```

It theoretically finds all the values within 5 pixels, and then eliminates the ones that are invalid. However, even on the first pixel, `(0,0)`, not all of the negatives are eliminated, and I get an `IndexError` later. It seems that when I iterate through `neighbors`, it does not pass every item in `neighbors`. Why is this, and how can I correct it?

Comment: If tried to answer your question below, but now I found a typo in your code which could be another cause of error. In your list comprehension you use both times `x+...` whereas it should probably be `(x+x2,y+y2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem could be, that you change your list while iterating over it. So instead of creating this list and removing illegal entries afterwards, I would directly create a list with only the allowed entries.
To do this you can use an `if` statement inside of your list comprehension:

```
[(x+x2,y+y2) for x2 in range(-5,5) for y2 in range(-5, 5) if x+x2>0 and x+x2<w and y+y2>0 and y+y2<h]
```

Another option to eliminate the illegal entries would be using another list comprehension. Then you could use the same code as you did to generate the neighbours and remove the illegal entries like this:

```
[(x,y) for (x,y) in neighbors if x>0 and y>0 and x<w and y<h]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. When you first answered, it didn't work, but your solution combined with that typo I missed worked perfectly. Thanks :)

Comment: At first I copied the typo, then I tried it with other values and noticed the error. :) I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured.